# how to draw a 3d shape with java, no other librarys or framework or anything

Tags: java, 3d, shapes

what i am trying to learn to do is draw a 3D shape in a JFrame.

All I want to use to do this is my IDE. If anyone can help with how to draw any 3d shape like a square, and if its possible, how to rotate it. Or could someone put a link to a recource for learning how to draw 3d shapes only with java like i said above. If anyone needs more detail please ask. (please do not ask me to do this differently if it is possible to do it this way).

thanks.

Comment: Swing alone does not support 3D Graphics as far as I know.

Comment: so it is not possible to draw anything 3d like this? no games or anything has 3d graphics without using library's and stuff?

Comment: If it IS possible, just curious as to why would you want to write all that code when it is easily accessible with libraries such as LWJGL and JOGL?

Comment: because i would prefer to learn how to do it, even if it is somthing basic that im displaying in 3d i would be happy to write 3000 lines of code if i understand it.

Answer (score 2):

Java has a 3-D package, which may or may not meet your criterion of "no other libraries or framework or anything":

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-138252.html

If it does, then you're *still* going to have to at least use the *2D* Java package:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html

Q: How do you draw 3D objects using the 2D primitives?

A: It's not necessarily difficult, depending on how in-depth you want to go.  At this simplest, just:

a) define a 3d coordinate system (normalized points 0.0 - 1.0 are always good)

b) write the functions to transform your 3D model into 2D coordinates

Lots of books (and tutorials), including:

- [Foley and Van Damm](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201848406)
- [Hearn and Baker](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131615300)

I'm assuming your goal is to "learn the basics".

Comment: i am trying to stay away from things like java3D untill i can atleaste write somthing by myself that displays anything in 3d. is it at all possible to do that? just a shape, nothing amazing like a full gam or scene, im just trying to do a shape. possible?

Comment: If you can draw a 2D shape, then you can draw a 3D one just the same with coordinate space conversions like the ones seen [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6139451/how-can-i-convert-3d-space-coordinates-to-2d-space-coordinates).